# Problem with WebGL and Google Sign In

Tags: firefox, webgl

I'm using Ubuntu 22.10 and Firefox 112.0.1 (64-bit). I had to disable WebGL in order to be able to sign in my Google Account. I believe other services are also affect. When WebGL is enabled, visiting https://get.webgl.org/ says it is all okay. I don't know the reason, but disabling it was the only solution I found to get to sign in Google. Is there any other solution? My notebook is a Thinkpad E480 with Radeon 550 RX 550 (drivers are installed and functional).